# ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHEN" Position

Tags: sql

What's wrong with this  query ?

```
SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN Step=6 THEN "#SQ1_1" END,
WHEN Step= 12 THEN "#SQ1_2"
ELSE Col_A
END AS "Layers"
FROM my_table
```

Comment: What database is this for?

Comment: Remove the `END, ` after the first `WHEN`

Comment: yes , what i'm doing is that i want to replace some cells on my DB : if  Step=6 THEN  i put "#SQ1_1" on the new column END,
WHEN Step= 12 THEN "#SQ1_2" on the new col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like  `END,` in the third line is a little too much. Proper formating code helps a lot.

Just try:

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN Step = 6 
              THEN "#SQ1_1"
            WHEN Step = 12 
              THEN "#SQ1_2"
            ELSE Col_A
       END AS "Layers"
  FROM my_table
```

Comment: Thank you Esteban , but i've a new message error : my_table does not exist , but i have the database and it exists

Comment: well... are you connected with the right database? simply write "USE dbname;" before your statement starts